# Using variables containing special characters

Tags: php

I am working on a project and a lot of my variables need to contain special characters such as {}[].'"!?/\=+- and many more what is the safest way to pass these variables back and forth between SQL, PHP, and output? and how can I prevent a variable from interfering with my code? Ie:

```
<?php
echo $var;
echo '$var';
echo "$var";
?>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements (with PDO/MySQLi) to insert into the database.  Use `htmlspecialchars` when echoing.

Comment: your variable **NAMES** are going to be stuff like `$foo{}!blah`? If so, your code seriously needs to get thrown in the garbage. variable names should never be dynamically generated to the point where they contain garbage like that.

Comment: The NAMES are not going to be that way, only the data contained within. Sorry if I was not clear enough on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to URL encode your data as soon as it is supplied. Then store it and when you are using it, urldecode it.

Something like

```
string urlencode ( string $str )
```

To encode and

```
string urldecode ( string $str )
```

To decode. This changes your "special" characters into safe characters.

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
<?php

${'[\*var'} = 1;
echo ${'[\*var'};
```

https://3v4l.org/5Dr93

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the **name** of a variable cannot contain special characters (other than the initial dollar sign `$` and underscores `_`). The **value** of a variable can contain whatever you'd like so long as you follow the rules of defining PHP strings.

The variable values won't interfere with your code. If you're concerned about it interfering with your output HTML, use `htmlspecialchars` as Rocket Hazmat suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PDO/MYSQL` for isnerting the data into the database..

For converting into html entites you can use [htmlchars()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp) function.